# script issue that does not make sense

Tags: sql, ruby

We have a script running that is pulling info from our AS400 and inserting data into our database.

In our admin control-panel we have a few override check-boxes. These boxes, when checked, set a '1' in the product table. This allows us to override data being sent for however long this is checked:

```
# check for WEBDB name override flag
if webdb_itm['override_name_and_description'] == '1'
  as400_itm[product_map['name']] = webdb_itm['name']
  as400_itm[product_map['description']] = webdb_itm['description']
end

# check for WEBDB price sheet sub category override flag
if webdb_itm['override_category'] == '1'
  as400_itm[product_map['ps_sub_category_id']] = webdb_itm['ps_sub_category_id']
end

# check for WEBDB as400 sub category override flag
if webdb_itm['override_as_sub_category'] == '1'
  as400_itm[product_map['as_sub_category_id']] = webdb_itm['as_sub_category_id']
end
```

This is a SQL dump so you can see the data is the same in the database:

```
override_category tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
override_as_sub_category tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
override_name_and_description tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
```

These are three of the check-boxes, and you can see they are all looking to see if the override is '1'.

The bottom two check-boxes work correctly, but the top one does not. If the top one is checked and the script is run, it will populate the data from the AS400 when it should not. The bottom two work correctly, and when checked, they just ignore the data.

I checked the database and saw `1,1,1`, so everything seems good.

Any ideas of what I am not seeing?

Comment: could you use `puts  webdb_itm['override_name_and_description']` just to see if it holds `1` or `"1"`? As *1* is different from *"1"*.

Comment: Why don't add assertions above the first condition and see yourself if there are values you are expecting ?

Comment: @Priti, all three are the same value and from a sql dump 'code'  `override_category` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `override_as_sub_category` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `override_name_and_description` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
'code' But for whatever reason the bottom two work fine?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if you have fields in a database set to be a certain type, such as an "int", your database driver or ORM will honor that and coerce/cast the values to the appropriate type for the language.

In Ruby, using Active Record or the MySQL or PostgreSQL drivers/gems or the Sequel ORM, you'll get back Integers. You don't say what you're using to talk to the database, but somewhere it should be coercing the values back to their Ruby equivalents, not returning everything as a character or a string. If it's a tool that was written in-house, well, there's a feature request in waiting.

That means, your code needs to compare to integers:

```
if webdb_itm['override_name_and_description'] == 1
  as400_itm[product_map['name']] = webdb_itm['name']
  as400_itm[product_map['description']] = webdb_itm['description']
end

# check for WEBDB price sheet sub category override flag
if webdb_itm['override_category'] == 1
  as400_itm[product_map['ps_sub_category_id']] = webdb_itm['ps_sub_category_id']
end

# check for WEBDB as400 sub category override flag
if webdb_itm['override_as_sub_category'] == 1
  as400_itm[product_map['as_sub_category_id']] = webdb_itm['as_sub_category_id']
end
```

That said, using integers to represent Boolean values, which is what a checkbox represents (on/off) is wrong, but that is probably a legacy thing, or maybe your AS400 DBM doesn't support Booleans.

Comment: It uses a ODBC to connect to the AS400 in a SQL naming conversion.

Comment: What are you using for your ODBC gem to manage the connection? Again, using something like Sequel or DataMapper should return you the correct types. Even DBI returns integers, strings, floats, etc.